# When climbing certain terrains that require an Athletics check, do you need to make the check again every turn?

Tags: dnd-5e, skills, movement

When you are climbing certain terrains that require an Athletics check, do you have to roll the Athletics check on every turn you climb? Or just once?

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance.

Comment: It seems you have experience with 3.5 edition or Pathfinder, the approach they both suggest works poorly with 5e, see the related question https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/159361/how-to-use-rules-did-this-change-between-editions-and-how/159363#159363

Answer (score 18, accepted):

### The rules don't specify that

> Athletics. {snip}
>    • You attempt to climb a sheer or slippery cliff, avoid hazards while scaling a wall, or cling to a surface while something is trying to knock you off.  (Basic Rules p. 62)

The PC rolls an ability check when the DM calls for one.

Ability Checks

> An ability check tests a character’s or monster’s innate talent and training in an effort to overcome a challenge. The DM calls for an ability check when a character or monster attempts an action (other than an attack) that has a chance of failure.
>   When the outcome is uncertain, the dice determine the results.   [Basic Rules  p. 61](https://media.wizards.com/2018/dnd/downloads/DnD_BasicRules_2018.pdf#page=61)

#### Ability checks, if you are the DM: roll once (recommendation)

Based on how our games have gone over the past 5 years, I recommend to you the following if you are a DM:
For a climb, check once, and adjudicate the spot as "half way up/down" the climb"

- Half way up or down is to simplify how much (and even if) falling damage applies.
- Exception to the general recommendation: if something changes conditions to make it harder.  If during the climb, for example, a rock slide starts,
  or a huge volume of water is unleashed and interferes with climbing -
  conditions that were not present at the start - a  re-check to handle
  that change is an option.

#### Why?

1. Simplicity
2. If you call for a roll each turn, [you will eventually force a failure](https://thealexandrian.net/wordpress/38798/roleplaying-games/gm-dont-list-2-rolling-to-failure).   It is somewhat penal to the player to do that.

#### Climbing in general costs half movement

> **Climbing, Swimming, and Crawling**
>   Each foot of movement costs 1 extra foot (2 extra feet in difficult
>   terrain) when you’re climbing, swimming, or crawling. You ignore this
>   extra cost if you have a climbing speed and use it to climb or a
>   swimming speed and use it to swim. At the DM’s option, climbing a
>   slippery vertical surface or one with few handholds requires a
>   successful Strength (Athletics) check. (Basic Rules, p. 67)

Many climbs require no DC/Ability check at all. (A lot of trees are very easy to climb).   It is only for the case where the climb is unaided, or has a chance to fail, that assigning a DC and calling for a roll is called for. (Some trees are all trunk until about 30' up: without special tools, they are  hard to climb)

References for further reading: DMG p. 237-238; 245

Comment: For a discussion of that issue: [The Alexandrian - GM Don't List #2: Rolling to failure](https://thealexandrian.net/wordpress/38798/roleplaying-games/gm-dont-list-2-rolling-to-failure)

Comment: @jhominal good point I added the link, thanks.  He's a good source for DM advice.